# HP QC 10 defect tracking - is editing the description a bad thing?

Tags: hp-quality-center, defects

When seeing a description in HP QC from a user which says "Button not working", it becomes a waste of time to chase them up to get replication steps, typing them up and then verifying them.

I have encouraged my team to *overwrite* the Description when a more clearer description becomes available. If the Description needs modification, because the issue is partially clear, this is also acceptable.

Once work begins only R&D comments are entered regarding movement of the QC, issues found, clarification needed. However, if an update is required to the Description - possibly clarifying a specific feature in more detail, the Description is modified and its update included in R&D comments.

Am I using or abusing the Description field? I have spoken to other users in other organisation who say it is forbidden to edit this. But when defects come through which are unspecific and unhelpful, in order to salvage a problematic issue, is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience with QC, we can edit the description, but it is not advisable to edit the defect status unnecessarily.

Thank you,
NaveenKumar N
For [www.QAInsights.com](http://www.QAInsights.com)